# tried deleted data but failed to delete from django database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I have created models.py, views.py, and urls.py and later on accordingly updated data.html file but when I click on the delete button it gives me an error. so the error file also attached for reference. Help appreciated and waiting for resolution.

**error file**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete/
Using the URLconf defined in student.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
export/ [name='export']
export-pdf [name='export-pdf']
register/ [name='register']
login/ [name='login']
home/ [name='home']
logout/ [name='logout']
upload/ [name='upload']
result/ [name='result']
dashbord/ [name='dashbord']
data/ [name='data']
delete/<int:id>
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, delete/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

**urls.py**

```
path('data/', views.data, name='data'),
 path('delete/<int:id>', views.delete),
```

**data.html**

```
<a href="/edit/{{ student.id }}"  class="btn btn-success"><span>Edit</span></a          
<a href="/delete/{{data1.id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

**views.py**

```
def data(request):
    data1 = Contact.objects.all()
    # myFilter = OrderFilter()
    dict = {
        "data1":data1
    }
    

    return render(request, 'data.html', context=dict)

# Delete Data
def delete(request):
    data1 = Contact.objects.all(id=id)
    data1.delete()
    return redirect("/data")
```

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import CharField
from django.contrib import admin

# Create your models here.


class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    address = models.TextField(max_length=50, default='')
    program = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, null=False, unique=True)
    w3review = models.TextField(max_length=60, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Cv(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='cv')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didnt specify the id number after
http://127.0.0.1/delete:8000/--id-here--

Comment: how do i get the id#

Comment: it automatically created. You just need to use this obj = Contact.objects.get(name=name_of_the_person) to access the id of the item and pass it to the url get it by doing obj.id and pass it to the url

Comment: still not working please, help me to overcome this

Comment: I hope this could help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/

Comment: can you review my code, i have read documentation, and not working in my case. this help really appricated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `get()` method instead of `all()` method. You code should be something like this:

```
def delete(self, request, id):
    data1 = Contact.objects.get(id=id)
    data1.delete()
    return redirect("/data")
```

And you must specify the id number according to @Ariel's Answer.